# How to restore content databases in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2013, content-database, restore, 2016

I have made **SharePoint 2013** Web Application **content database backup**.

Now I'm working on to restore **content database** into **SharePoint 2016** farm.

please guide me with some steps..

Comment: Is ur 2016 farm ready?

Comment: Yes. my 2016 farm is ready..!

Answer (score 7):

- In SharePoint 2016 > Create A new web application.
- Then Create a new site collection.
- Go back to Application Management > Manage Content database.
- Click on Content Database name > Check Remove Content Database > OK.
- Or use `Dismount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentdBName>"`
- Open SQL Management Studio.
- Restore your database.
- then run the following `Mount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentDb>" -DatabaseServer "<DbServer>" -WebApplication http://SiteName`

For more details check [Restore / Migrate a SharePoint Web Application to another farm from SQL Database Backup](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)

If you need to perform full upgrade process , Check also  [Create the SharePoint Server 2016 farm for a database attach upgrade](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263026(v=office.16).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In that case

- make sure your sharepoint farm is min sp1 or higher level.
- if you have any customization in 2013 which need for sites collection in that db then must apply in 2016.
- you need to restore the content db to 2016 farm
- once restore completed then mount the database to 2016 web app by this `Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name DatabaseName -DatabaseServer ServerName -WebApplication URLe` you can use skip upgrade parameter if you don't want to upgrade. You can do it later
- now test ur upgrade

This is really good technet article: [Upgrade content databases to SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299(v=office.16).aspx)